# HTML Design Issue

Tags: html, dom

I have a issue in html designing. when I create a new div into id of leftbox DIV then this divs falls down. but when I use position absolute in new divs it works perfectly. please help

```css
#cont {
  width: 60%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ff3333;
}

#leftbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background: #00ff00;
}

#rightbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cont">
    <div id="leftbox">
      <div>my div</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbox"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You said something about it working? What's the question?

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ashwinik47/mjk5mssj/

Answer (score 0):

apply below style to new div which inserted into leftbox div.

```
float:left;
```

Comment: but the question is why its fall down.

Comment: if you will use overflow: auto; to leftbox it will also work. the inner div is going outside of wrapper.

Comment: first time i thought so, But my width and height of this div is smaller then the parent div. and I used display inline block for this. but still its fall down

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ashwinik47/mjk5mssj